# cannot sign into visual studio and community edition trial period expired

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I installed community edition of Visual Studio more than a month ago.
Didn't realize that you had to go through some registration process.
It says that trial period expired.
I uninstalled, and tried to re-install.
But then it is now upgraded to Visual Studio 2017, which I don't want.
So I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 and found link for 2015.
I was able to install it.
But it still knows that my trial period expired.
When I try to sign in, it tells me:
Sorry, we ran into a problem.  Please try again later.

This is wrong.  The service is not down.

The message happens all the time.

I saw some troubleshooting steps on this earlier in other posts, but those did not work for me....

Comment: i solved problem by not using WIFI, and hard-wiring into the router/modem.  Now, does anybody know why that worked?  If so, I will give mark that as answer accepted.  Just put in details to not use "WIFI" and I will give you the credit if you can tell me why that worked.

Answer (score 0):

i solved problem by not using WIFI, and hard-wiring laptop into the router/modem. Now, does anybody know why this worked?